# Where's this wall painting in Warsaw?

Tags: warsaw, artworks

Can anyone tell me where I can find this painting?

[image]
Thanks so much

Comment: Users are encouraged to show some research effort. I found the answer in the very first google hit for "Warsaw street art".

Answer (score 5):

According to [this page](https://www.inyourpocket.com/warsaw/warsaw-fight-club_152833v), the piece was created in 2015 by Irish artist Conor Harrington, and is located at Ul. Środkowa 17 in the Praga district of Warsaw. [Google street view](https://goo.gl/maps/Pe9bA4zxYWfAmSK77) confirms that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to try [Google Image Search](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1325808?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) and [Google Lens](https://lens.google.com/) first. E.g. in the results searching with your image with Google Lens, you will see many results showing the same art from Conor Harrington indicating its location:

[image]

Comment: I didnt know about Google Lens, thank you!